# Android display a specific Image in ViewPager

Tags: android

I am using ViewPager to switch images and it works. 
I have grid view and when i click an image on it. that same image opens OKay. But when i switch between images it starts from the beginning leaving the first.

for example.
I have int[5] images.
 If id = 3
then it displays image  3 1 2 3 4. the image is 3 is repeated and image[0] is not displayed.

I want it to 4 if i swipe right and 2 if i swipe left.

If you still can't understand. here is the video link of my app. 
https://youtu.be/HI-BYz4M8ms

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup viewGroup, int position)
{
    if(position == 0) {
        position = id;
    }
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    viewGroup.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}
```

Comment: what's an `id` in your if statment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to display your ViewPager as normal and call `viewpager.setCurrentItem(itemIndex)` to go to the position of your selected image.

What you're doing at the moment is replacing the first image by the selected one. So if the selected one is not the first one, the image 0 is not displayed and the selected one is displayed twice.

Comment: When the user clicks on the button (or image in OP's question). `viewpager` is the instance of your ViewPager that you've retrieved using `findViewById(R.id.my_viewpager)` in your Activity

Comment: its not working for some reason this is code:  `mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(ImageActivity.this, object,loc);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(loc);
        // Adding the Adapter to the ViewPager
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);`